# Mousewheel not working with jScrollPane in IE8 (no iframe!)

Tags: javascript, jquery, jscrollpane

I have and issue with scrolling content of a jScrollPane div using the mousewheel, which I don't seem to get working in IE8. In Chrome i'ts working correctly. I've red about simular issues but those cases the problem was with an iframe being used, which I don't. I included the mouswheel plugin and as far as I know I've set up everything correctly.

The inclusion of the necessary files:

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/css/jquery.jscrollpane.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/js/libs/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/js/libs/jquery.mousewheel.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/js/libs/jquery.jscrollpane.min.js"></script>
```

Apply jScrollPane:

```
$("#chatlog").jScrollPane({
    autoReinitialise: true,
    autoReinitialiseDelay: 100,
    maintainPosition: true,
    stickToBottom: true,
    verticalDragMinHeight: 13,
    verticalDragMaxHeight: 13
});
```

CSS:

```
#chatlog {
    position: relative;
    height: 400px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

I've set up a very simple testpage that has this issue:

http://www.webtrail.nl/jscrollpane-example

Thanks!

Comment: errors in console? demo page with your code?

Comment: nope, no errors. I've just set up a test page here: http://www.webtrail.nl/jscrollpane-example

Comment: Have you tried it on firefox (as the mousewheel is not working on it either, at least for me). I think this has something to do with the mousewheel plugin. Try adding a console.log() or alert() into the handler() function of the plugin to determine what the delta is returning.

Comment: Same problem in FF, indead. Problem solved now. See below...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution was simple. I've downloaded and included the newest version of the jquery mousewheel plugin and the problem was solved:

https://github.com/brandonaaron/jquery-mousewheel/downloads

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and replaced my old jquery 1.5 to jquery 1.7, now it's working fine.